# How to change TabView dot indicator position SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

i want to change TabView dot indicator position is there a way to do that ? .

```
   TabView {
            
            ForEach(data.options ?? [],id:\.id) { item in
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewParser.create(item: item,index: item.typeArry ?? [])) {
                    
                    AnimatedImage(url: URL(string : item.image ?? ""))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width:CGFloat(getWidth(column: data.column ?? 1)))
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                }
                
                
            }.frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height:CGFloat(getHeight(ratio: data.ratio ?? 1, column: data.column ?? 1)))
            
            
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can't. You can only hide the indicators and create a custom ones.

Comment: @pawello2222 Okay thank you for answer.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score -2):

You have to adjust the height of the tab view. That in turn changes the position of the paging indicator.

Example:

```
TabView {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
```

This example will position the indicator inside the view like so:

[image]

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it just moves the view. What if you want the dots to be at the bottom of the view without any padding? Or what if you want the dots at the top? AFAIK the only solution is to create custom indicators.